# How to make an <input type="text"> 2em wider than a <span>

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `<span>` element in my HTML, which  can change its contents by javascript. However, for styling purposes, I would like the `<input type="text">` which I have above it to always remain **2em** wider. I don't mind using JQuery.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Things I've tried:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var tips = document.getElementById('usageTip');
  var name = document.getElementById('name');
  name.setAttribute("width", tips.style.width.valueOf + 2);
});
```

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var tips = document.getElementById('usageTip');
  var name = document.getElementById('name');
  name.setAttribute("width", tips.style.width.value + 2);
});
```

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var tips = document.getElementById('usageTip');
  var name = document.getElementById('name');
  name.setAttribute("width", tips.style.width);
});
```

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var tips = document.getElementById('usageTip');
  var name = document.getElementById('name');
  name.setAttribute("width", tips.width + 2);
});
```

Bear in mind that the CSS specifies the width of the `name` input box as
`width:20em;`
and the `tips` span is not specified (auto).

Comment: Hi, could you add what you've already tried so far ?

Comment: Sure, adding now. Sorry I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery you can do :

```
$('#name').css( "width", "calc("+$("#usageTip").width()+"px + 2em)" );
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#resize').click(function() {
    $('#inp').css( "width", "calc("+$("#sp").width()+"px + 2em)" );
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span style="background:#faa" id="sp">Content of the span</span>
<br/>
<input type="text" id="inp">
<br/>

<input type="button" id="resize" value="resize" />
```

Answer (score 0):

no Jquery demo, do you mean this ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Demo</title>
</head>

<body>
 <style>
  .box_wrap {
   display: inline-block;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   padding:2rem;
   background: #f0f0f0;
  }

  .box {
   outline: none;
  }
 </style>
    <span class="box_wrap">
        <input type="text" id="box" class="box"/>
    </span>
    <script>
 var input = document.querySelector("#box");
 var widht = 20;

    input.style.width = widht + "em";
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```